# I am trying to do a sum on a collection key and can't seem to figure it out

Tags: laravel, sum, sql-order-by

I have an almost complete system in Laravel 5.4, but I am having difficulty using sum on a key in a collection.

I've tried a series of code snippets of my own and also a variety of misleading code in the forums (well according to my experience).

Here is the collection:

```
Collection {#263 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    5 => Collection {#224 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▼
        0 => {#213 ▼
          +"id": 1
          +"portfolio_id": 5
          +"type": "Secured Note"
          +"date": "2018-11-18"
          +"inv_amount": "300000"
          +"return_rate": "10%"
          +"payment_amount": "7500"
          +"inv_term": "18 Months"
          +"payment_schedule": "Monthly"
          +"account_info": "US BANK 4532"
          +"pdffiles": null
          +"created_at": "2019-04-19 01:51:53"
          +"updated_at": "2019-04-19 11:53:03"
          +"user_id": 1
          +"hide": null
          +"contract": null
          +"reports": null
          +"taxdocs": null
        }
        1 => {#252 ▶}
        2 => {#253 ▶}
        3 => {#254 ▶}
        4 => {#255 ▶}
        5 => {#256 ▶}
        6 => {#257 ▶}
        7 => {#258 ▶}
        8 => {#259 ▶}
        9 => {#260 ▶}
      ]
    }
    6 => Collection {#261 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => {#218 ▼
          +"id": 2
          +"portfolio_id": 6
          +"type": "Secured Note"
          +"date": "2018-09-15"
          +"inv_amount": "350000"
          +"return_rate": "12%"
          +"payment_amount": "7500"
          +"inv_term": "24 Months"
          +"payment_schedule": "Monthly"
          +"account_info": "US BANK 4532"
          +"pdffiles": null
          +"created_at": "2019-04-19 01:53:46"
          +"updated_at": "2019-04-19 03:14:03"
          +"user_id": 1
          +"hide": null
          +"contract": null
          +"reports": null
          +"taxdocs": null
        }
      ]
    }
    7 => Collection {#262 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => {#238 ▼
          +"id": 3
          +"portfolio_id": 7
          +"type": "Secured Note"
          +"date": "2018-06-11"
          +"inv_amount": "380000"
          +"return_rate": "15%"
          +"payment_amount": "8900"
          +"inv_term": "36 Months"
          +"payment_schedule": "Monthly"
          +"account_info": "US BANK 4532"
          +"pdffiles": null
          +"created_at": "2019-04-19 01:54:45"
          +"updated_at": "2019-04-24 00:38:21"
          +"user_id": 1
          +"hide": null
          +"contract": null
          +"reports": null
          +"taxdocs": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here is what is generating it in the controller:

```
$grouped = DB::table('funds')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('portfolio_id');
dd($grouped);
```

The Fund model belongsTo Portfolio and the Portfolio Model hasMany Funds.

From the collection, I have 3 portfolios. I am trying the sum the payment_amount pay for each of the 3 generated from groupBy.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `groupBy()` before the `get()`. Also you need to use SUM on the select.

```
$grouped = DB::table('funds')
    ->select(DB::raw("portfolio_id, SUM(payment_amount)"))
    ->groupBy('portfolio_id')
    ->get();
dd($grouped);
```

Please also take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates

Comment: I'll be more thorough with the documentation also.

Comment: I did, but received this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Got it. First time posting! Thanks again.